# Difference between Bolt Action vs All Sniper Rifle in Sniper Training mode

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds, mobile

When I play Sniper Training Mode in PUBG mobile sometimes I get "All Rifles" or "Bolt Action" written in bottom right of screen. So what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Your asking the diffrence between the Bolt Action Sniper Rifile and all other Rifles?

Comment: yes with respect to pubg moblle game mode

Comment: This link might help you:  https://pubg.me/weapons/sniper-rifles                    This shows the stats of all curent sniper rifles. Ive never played PUBG but I found this useful link for you.

Comment: please anyone i want a solid answer

Comment: Okay ill have an answer by today.

Comment: please tell the reason for down voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is indicating which pool of weapons are available for the round.
Bolt Action refers to sniper rifles which do not have a magazine - the weapon must be  reloaded after each shot (causing the scope view to end & potentially leading to you losing sight of your target as they scramble for cover).  For more information on the type of rifle being modelled, please see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_action.

All Rifles expands this out to include sniper rifles with an ammunition magazine as well (allowing multiple shots without the need to reload).

Generally speaking, the bolt action rifles are more powerful than those with a magazine, helping to balance the inconvenience of needing to scope out and reload after each shot.  Rifles with a magazine are less powerful but more forgiving, allowing for several follow up shots in quick succession.